I'm getting a Shopify CORS error after redirection
I'm getting a CORS error when trying to authenticate with Shopify.
Here's my backend code:
  await shopify.auth.begin({
    shop: shopify.utils.sanitizeShop(account.integrations.shopify.shop, true)!,
    callbackPath: '/integrations/shopify/auth/callback',
    isOnline: false,
    rawRequest: req,
    rawResponse: res,
  })

It returns a 302 as expected. But the browser then tries to open the URL and fails on CORS.

What did I do wrong?
I tried using 'no-cors' mode but it doesn't work
